# Convert Java String in ISO timestamp format to SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date

I am trying to convert a String in ISO timestamp format to a `SimpleDateFormat` like so:

```
public static void convertDate () {
  String timestamp = DateFormatUtils.ISO_DATETIME_TIME_ZONE_FORMAT.format(new Date());
  DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");
  Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(timestamp);  
}
```

The above code throws the following exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
```

Comment: What is the value of the `timestamp` String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are parsing date's from XML in ISO 8601 format you can use the JAXB parser.

[Check this post for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)